# How to write vertical text in opera 9.5?

Tags: html, css, canvas, svg, vertical-text

Does somebody know how to draw vertical text in opera 9.5? As I can see in "caniuse", opera 9.5 doesn't support svg, `-o-transform: rotate(-90deg), writing-mode:tb-rl` and I don't know any methods to do this. Help me please.

Comment: I discovered that opera 9.5 supports canvas (omg), so i can draw rect or circle, but not text `context.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 50);`

Comment: It's simply not supported on that ancient version. You could provide individual positions for each glyph as a workaround I suppose.